# Drag and drop (replace) in HTML 5

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

i have menu from where can drag elements and drop into another div, it works. But how i can do the replacement of elements??

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function OnDragEnter (){
}
function drop(ev) { 
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = "newId";
    ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.removeChild(ev.target.childNodes[0]);
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```